# Compute distances between points in UTM 32 coordinates and world countries centroids in WGS 84 with R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, coordinates, utm

I have a set of points for Italian cities in UTM 32 N (CRS=EPSG:32632) and I have computed the distances between them using R.

Now I would like to compute linear distances also between a subgroup of these Italian cities and world countries, using their centroids as reference points.

The centroids coordinates I have found for world countries use EPSG:4326 WGS 84 as the reference system.

Now I'm wondering what is the best way to combinate these two sets of coordinates and compute distances. If I have correctly understood I can not use the UTM 32 N for other zones.

Should I convert the Italian coordinates into EPSG:4326 WGS 84?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Should I convert the Italian coordinates into epsg:4326 wgs84?"

Yes. You should be using the `sf` package for spatial data, and use `st_transform` to convert between coordinate systems. Then the `st_distance` function will compute the distance along the surface of the earth as a spherical or ellipsoidal model. Details in the help.

You could also recompute your city distances using spherical distances, you may find small differences between the spherical distance and the planar distance in UTM coordinates, which will be greatest for cities far apart.

Comment: I have used this specification from the italian cities utm coordinates: utm = st_as_sf(comuni,coords = c("X_WGS84_32N", "Y_WGS84_32N"), crs="32632") . Is it correct to use crs = 4326 in the st_transform function?Thank you

Comment: Yes, coordinate reference systems can be referred to in the `sf` package as numbers or character strings. A numeric crs like `4326` is equivalent to a character crs like `"EPSG:4326"`.